Matplotlib Ordered Bars in Mosaic Plot Work in Jupyter but Not in Plotly App
Question
I'm working on a Python application that generates a mosaic plot using Matplotlib, and I'm embedding this plot within a Plotly Dash application. The problem I'm facing is that the bars in the mosaic plot are ordered correctly when I run the code in a Jupyter Notebook, but the order is incorrect when I run the same code within the Plotly app.
Here’s a minimal reproductible example:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
import base64

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'adc1[SQ001]': ['1 time', '2 times', 'Never', 'more than 5 times', 'Never',
                     '3 times', 'Never', 'Never', 'Never', '1 time',
                     '1 time', 'Never', 'Never', '3 times', 'more than 5 times',
                     '1 time', 'more than 5 times', '1 time', 'Never', '4 times'],
    'CE11': ['Exact and Earth Sciences', 'Human Sciences', 'Health Sciences', 
             'Linguistics, Letters and Arts', 'Exact and Earth Sciences', 'Agrarian Sciences',
             'Biological Sciences', 'Exact and Earth Sciences', 'Agrarian Sciences',
             'Engineering', 'Health Sciences', 'Biological Sciences', 'Engineering',
             'Human Sciences', 'Biological Sciences', 'Exact and Earth Sciences',
             'Human Sciences', 'Agrarian Sciences', 'Health Sciences',
             'Exact and Earth Sciences']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define ordered categories
ordered_categories = ['Never', '1 time', '2 times', '3 times', '4 times', '5 times', 'more than 5 times']

# Convert the column to an ordered categorical type
df['adc1[SQ001]'] = pd.Categorical(df['adc1[SQ001]'], categories=ordered_categories, ordered=True)

# Create the contingency table
contingency_table = pd.crosstab(df['adc1[SQ001]'], df['CE11'], observed=False)
contingency_table = contingency_table.reindex(ordered_categories, axis=0)

# Calculate the chi-square test
chi2_stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(contingency_table)
residuals = (contingency_table - expected) / np.sqrt(expected)

# Function to map block colors based on Pearson residuals
def residual_color(key):
    if key[1] in residuals.index and key[0] in residuals.columns:
        value = residuals.loc[key[1], key[0]]
        if value >= 4:
            return {'color': 'red'}
        elif value >= 2:
            return {'color': 'lightcoral'}
        elif value <= -4:
            return {'color': 'blue'}
        elif value <= -2:
            return {'color': 'dodgerblue'}
        else:
            return {'color': 'lightgrey'}
    else:
        return {'color': 'lightgrey'}

# Create the mosaic plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
mosaic(df, ['CE11', 'adc1[SQ001]'], properties=residual_color, ax=ax, gap=0.02, labelizer=lambda k: '')

# Add a color legend for Pearson residuals
bounds = [-4, -2, 2, 4]
cmap = plt.cm.RdBu_r
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=-4, vmax=4)

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ax=ax, ticks=[-4, -2, 2, 4])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['<= -4', '-2', '2', '>= 4'])
cbar.ax.text(0.5, -0.1, f'p-value: {p:.3f}', transform=cbar.ax.transAxes, fontsize=12, 
             verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='center', 
             bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round,pad=0.5'))

# Adjust x-axis labels
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

# Show the plot
plt.show()

Problem:
In the Jupyter Notebook, the bars in the mosaic plot are correctly ordered as specified in ordered_categories.
However, when running this code in a Plotly Dash app, the bars are not ordered as expected.
What I've Tried:
Verified that the column is correctly converted to a categorical type with the desired order.
Reindexed the contingency table based on ordered_categories.
Checked for any differences between the environment in Jupyter and the Plotly app.
Additional Information:
The Plotly app uses Matplotlib to generate the plot, which is then encoded as a base64 image and embedded in the app.
Question:
Why is the bar order different when the code is executed in a Plotly app, and how can I ensure that the bars in the mosaic plot are ordered correctly in both environments?

Hi Marcelo, do you mind to produce a [mcve]? What are df activity_col and interest_var

sure thing! I'll update the question
